# Maven: How to relase an artifact without any project specific settings like parent pom or scm?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

i have the task to build an artifact of an application that should be shipped to a customer. The artifact is a client-jar that can be used to access an ejb-application on a server.

As it is build out of a multi-module project, the artifact's pom contains the reference to a parent pom and scm information that should not be shipped to the customer.

Is there a maven way to remove those information or, in case of the parent pom, to resolve the parent pom and include its data in the client-jar's pom directly.
The customers will not have access to our intern maven repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove all information from META-INF, see:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

And you can use maven assembly plugin (or shade) to build jar file with all dependencies.